# Cannot read property 'token' of undefined in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, token

```
let headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "token=" + this.props.login.token,
            "Accept-Language": this.props.language.language,
        };
```

Comment: login prop is undefined. How do you pass the login prop to the component? Please give more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing token in wrong way

instead of writing like this

```
"Authorization": "token=" + this.props.login.token,
```

define like this

```
"Authorization": "bearer " + this.props.login.token,
```

Sample of axios code

```
axios.post('api_ulr', {
  headers: {'Authorization': "bearer " + this.props.login.token}
  }
).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
Actually when calling a component and if you don't provide props along with that, we get this error "Cannot read property 'token' of undefined". So just pass the props along with the component like {...this.props} and it works well.